# Bending arrows around entries and double arrow style variant with Xy-pic?

Tags: xy-pic

I have the following Xy-pic commands in Lyx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ & A\\
 & B\ar@2`l/10pt[ld]`[d][ldr]\\
 & C\ar@2[u]\\
 & D\ar@2`l/10pt[lu]`[u][lur]
}
\end{document}
```

The above input produces:

[image: No double arrows around bend]

I have not found a way to produce the same double arrow style where the bending occurs. Any ideas how to fix, or what to add to the above commands in Xy-pic? Any other approach in Xy-pic producing the wanted results is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure Xy-pic supports this. It can be done with TikZ, though.

Comment: Have a look at the [xypic manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf). Exercise 13 is about drawing a bent double arrow; its solution is on page 14. But honestly, I wouldn't invest any time into this approach from 15 years ago unless you have to extend legacy code. Tikz (in particular its manual) might seem overwhelming in the beginning, but offers many more possibilities ...

Answer (score 2):

Using TikZ-CD (`cd` library) and combining the paths of `ext.paths.ortho` with the [`nfold` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642548) that was made for TikZ-CD this can be achieved easily.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, ext.paths.ortho, nfold}
\tikzcdset{
  /utils/temp/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688891
    !#1/.style={/tikz/ortho/#1 distance={##1},
                /tikz/to path={r-#1(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}},
  /utils/temp=lr}% /utils/temp/.list={lr, rl, du, ud} for all
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/ortho/udlr distance=10mm]
A \\
B \dar[Rightarrow, nfold, !lr, rounded corners=10pt] \\
C \uar[Rightarrow] \\
D \uar[Rightarrow, nfold, !lr, rounded corners=10pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]